# Overriding a package method in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, package

I'm building a friends package, and I need to store some data on every new user document that gets created. I looked in the docs, and I found `Accounts.onCreateUser`. The docs specifically state that it can only be called once, other calls will override the previously specified behaviour.

So what I did is:

- Store the old function
- Override the actual `onCreateUser` function with one that adds the required data
- That new function then calls the old one after adding my data

.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    var _onCreateUser = Accounts.onCreateUser.bind(Accounts);
    // Since onCreateUser overrides default behavior, and we don't want to restrict package users
    // by removing the onCreateUser function, we override onCreateUser to modify the user document before the regular onCreateUser call.
    Accounts.onCreateUser = function (func) {
        console.log('onCreateUser definition');
        _onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
            console.log('onCreateUser call, the user should now have a profile');
            if (!user.profile) {
                user.profile = options.profile || {};
            }
            if (!user.profile.friends) {
                user.profile.friends = [];
            }
            return func(options, user);
        });
    };
}
```

The problem is, if I look in my server logs, I never see either logs `onCreateUser definition` or `onCreateUser call, ...` meaning this code never actually runs.

Am I doing something wrong with trying to override provided package behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

`Accounts.onCreateUser` is what you call to bind your custom functions. The "only call once" means you can only bind ONE custom function. *If nothing else binds a custom function, onCreateUser will never be called*

Eg.if you just want to add profile & friends as per your code, just do:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
        console.log('onCreateUser call, the user should now have a profile');
        if (!user.profile) {
            user.profile = options.profile || {};
        }
        if (!user.profile.friends) {
            user.profile.friends = [];
        }
        return user;
});
```

---

Based on your comment, I would suggest creating an issue / submitting a pull request to Meteor to allow the `Accounts.onCreateUser` to append each function to an array of hooks.

The code you'd need to modify is in [`Accounts.insertUserDoc`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/release/METEOR%400.9.0.1/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L981)

Comment: The problem is that this onCreateUser call is in a package. When I do it like your example, people who would use my package would overwrite my package's custom onCreateUser behavior when they bind a function to onCreateUser in their application code, right?

Comment: Yep, but then, if they don't call `Accounts.onCreateUser` your code will never be run.